# k fold cross validation: nominal predictor level appears in the test data but not the training data

Tags: cross-validation, categorical-data

I wrote my own cross validation function for model output in R (`lm`, `glm` and so on; named `MOD_k_fold_r2` in [my R package](https://github.com/Deleetdk/kirkegaard)). It works for nominal predictors as well. In a few rare cases, a level of the nominal predictors does not appear in the training data, but does appear in the test data. When this happens, the `predict` function throws an error because it doesn't know which beta to assign to this new level and therefore it can't predict the Y values for the cases.

Is there any standard way to deal with this? Perhaps assign the beta a 0 coefficient manually? This would require scoring the new cases manually instead of using the `predict` function I think. Currently, I am instead just disregarding these runs that produce errors and rely on the remaining runs. This is a rare problem for most datasets.

**Update**

Proposals so far:

- Skip runs that use test data that have levels that do not appear in the training data.
- Use stratified sampling to make sure that all training datasets include at least one case with each level.
- If levels are missing, then insert pseudocases with arbitrary datapoints, e.g. mean of all values.

Comment: One way to avoid this is to deliberately form the training set such that all levels of each nominal predictor are represented at least once in the training set. I have no idea what the "standard" way of dealing with this is though.

Comment: @JakeWestfall: "stratification" should be a start point to look this up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing one hot encoding without a reference level, then set all encoded features of that test instance to zero. I don't know if that's common practice, but it sounds logical.

If it's an ordered factor, then you will probably transform it to a numeric feature, and the transformation would probably still applies for new levels.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling), i.e. constraining your train/test splits so that they have (approximately) the same relative frequencies for your predictor levels.

However, I think it worth considering whether the current behavior is actually wanted: So random splitting with non-negligible frequency results in sets that do not cover all predictor levels. Can you consider such a set representative for whatever the application is?
I've been working with such small sample sizes and went for stratified splitting. But I insist that thinking hard about the data and the consequences of working with such small samples is at least as necessary as fixing the pure computational error.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to warn the user when this happens.  But if robustness and ease of use are important, you might consider a preprocessing step that changes the missing nominal values to an arbitrary value that was in the training data.