# When are analytic standard errors more accurate than bootstrapped standard errors?

Tags: bootstrap, standard-error

Given the performance of modern computers, doing even a large number of bootstraps to estimate a given model's parameters' standard errors usually only takes a few seconds. Given that the bootstrap doesn't have to make strong assumptions about the data it usually results in either the same or somewhat larger and more accurate standard errors. Thus, I am wondering when it is time to switch to using bootstrapped standard errors by default, e.g. in R package functions. (I know that in some situations, cross-validation and bootstrapping can cause problems [due to stratification in the dataset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213837/k-fold-cross-validation-nominal-predictor-level-appears-in-the-test-data-but-no), so one might not always be able to easily switch to them.)

This made me wonder, however, are there circumstances where analytic methods are superior? [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4784504/) mentions some examples. How common are they in real life?

Comment: Keep in mind that estimates are only as accurate as can be expected for the original sample size.  Increasing the number of bootstrap replications only make the estimate converge to the bootstrap estimate.